# Merge 2 rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

In table or some result of `JOIN` exists 2 rows with same `Email` but has different other values.

Example:

```
Email          -/- Operation1 (BIT) -/- Operation2 (BIT)
test@email.com -/- 1          -/- 0
test@email.com -/- 0          -/- 1
```

How can I group rows by `Email` and select them in next format (according to sample)

```
Email          -/- Operation1 (BIT) -/- Operation2 (BIT)
test@email.com -/- 1          -/- 1
```

If Operation1 is `TRUE` in one row then in result return `TRUE`

Comment: Pretty hard to tell much of anything from the sparse details posted here. Maybe as simple as using MAX and grouping by email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in your table for Bit Fields the below query will work in SQL SERVER 2008

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
email VARCHAR(30),
Operation1 BIT,
Operation2 BIT
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES('test@email.com',1,0)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES('test@email.com',0,1)

-- METHOD 1
SELECT email,
MAX(CASE WHEN Operation1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Operation1,
MAX(CASE WHEN Operation2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Operation2
FROM #temp GROUP BY email

-- METHOD 2
SELECT email,MAX(CONVERT(INT,Operation1)) AS Operation1,
MAX(CONVERT(INT,Operation2)) AS Operation2
FROM #temp GROUP BY email


--DROP TABLE #TEMP
```